# Merge with priority

Tags: rx-java2

I use Flowable.merge operator with buffer of size 1 for each from two upstream.

```
Flowable.merge(sources, 2, 1)
.observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1)
```

Is possible use priority for one from streams when is called request(1) from downstream?
When both streams have item in queue (full) than should be emitted item (call of request(1)) of first source.

Sources can be two subjects.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a specialized observable that implemented the priority handling.

The operator would construct two subscribers and subscribe them to the two observer chains. Each subscriber would then handle the merging of the streams. The "priority one" subscriber would receive a value, check if the down stream had requested a value and send it on. The "priority two" subscriber would receive a value and hold on to it if there was a "priority one" value waiting to be sent. Each subscriber would issue `request(1)` whenever it emitted a value downstream.

Fortunately, RxJava is open source, and, even more fortunately, there are several blogs that describe the proper implementation of RxJava operators. This [blog](http://akarnokd.blogspot.ca/) by David Karnok has very well written descriptions of implementing many operators. His postings describe in excellent detail how to avoid the many pitfalls of threaded data structure access.